# MySQL JDBC Datasource lookup fails after updating to mysql-connector-java-5.1.44

Tags: mysql, exception, jdbc, datasource, connection-pool

Consider following code snippet:

```
try
{//try to connect
    conn = DatasourceProvider.getDatasource("java:comp/env/jdbc/mysql/my_db").getConnection();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{//failed to acquire connection from the pool, retry
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I run it with `mysql-connector-java-5.1.10-bin.jar` loaded in tomcat 8.5 it works gracefully, but when I update to `mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar` it throws following exception:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/mysql/my_db] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:816)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:827)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:827)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:173)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:163)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
```

This happens on both MySQL5.6 and MySQL5.7.
Any Idea?

Comment: Check the tomcat server logs, you probably missed an exception when it was initializing the data source.

Comment: There is no other exception in tomcat logs